# How to implement react-i18next in a routes.js file

Tags: reactjs, i18next

I have a left nav bar that utilises my admin.js file. This in turn imports my routes.js file which returns a const with an array. Is it possible to translate these items in any way using react-i18next without breaking the "hooks" rules?

Please note I've implemented react-i18next on my content pages and they work well. Not included any react-i18next imports on below code.

My Admin.js file

```
import React from "react";
import cx from "classnames";
import { Switch, Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
// creates a beautiful scrollbar
import PerfectScrollbar from "perfect-scrollbar";
import "perfect-scrollbar/css/perfect-scrollbar.css";

// @material-ui/core components
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

// core components
import AdminNavbar from "components/Navbars/AdminNavbar.js";
import Footer from "components/Footer/Footer.js";
import Sidebar from "components/Sidebar/Sidebar.js";
import FixedPlugin from "components/FixedPlugin/FixedPlugin.js";

import routes from "routes.js";

import styles from "assets/jss/material-dashboard-pro-react/layouts/adminStyle.js";

var ps;

const useStyles = makeStyles(styles);

export default function Dashboard(props) {
  const { ...rest } = props;
  // states and functions
  const [mobileOpen, setMobileOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [miniActive, setMiniActive] = React.useState(false);
  const [image, setImage] = React.useState(require("assets/img/sidebar-2.jpg"));
  const [color, setColor] = React.useState("blue");
  const [bgColor, setBgColor] = React.useState("black");
  // const [hasImage, setHasImage] = React.useState(true);
  const [fixedClasses, setFixedClasses] = React.useState("dropdown");
  const [logo, setLogo] = React.useState(require("assets/img/logo-white.svg"));
  // styles
  const classes = useStyles();
  const mainPanelClasses =
    classes.mainPanel +
    " " +
    cx({
      [classes.mainPanelSidebarMini]: miniActive,
      [classes.mainPanelWithPerfectScrollbar]:
        navigator.platform.indexOf("Win") > -1
    });
  // ref for main panel div
  const mainPanel = React.createRef();
  // effect instead of componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate and componentWillUnmount
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (navigator.platform.indexOf("Win") > -1) {
      ps = new PerfectScrollbar(mainPanel.current, {
        suppressScrollX: true,
        suppressScrollY: false
      });
      document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
    }
    window.addEventListener("resize", resizeFunction);

    // Specify how to clean up after this effect:
    return function cleanup() {
      if (navigator.platform.indexOf("Win") > -1) {
        ps.destroy();
      }
      window.removeEventListener("resize", resizeFunction);
    };
  });
  // functions for changeing the states from components
  const handleImageClick = image => {
    setImage(image);
  };
  const handleColorClick = color => {
    setColor(color);
  };
  const handleBgColorClick = bgColor => {
    switch (bgColor) {
      case "white":
        setLogo(require("assets/img/logo.svg"));
        break;
      default:
        setLogo(require("assets/img/logo-white.svg"));
        break;
    }
    setBgColor(bgColor);
  };
  const handleFixedClick = () => {
    if (fixedClasses === "dropdown") {
      setFixedClasses("dropdown show");
    } else {
      setFixedClasses("dropdown");
    }
  };
  const handleDrawerToggle = () => {
    setMobileOpen(!mobileOpen);
  };
  const getRoute = () => {
    return window.location.pathname !== "/admin/full-screen-maps";
  };
  const getActiveRoute = routes => {
    let activeRoute = "Default Brand Text";
    for (let i = 0; i < routes.length; i++) {
      if (routes[i].collapse) {
        let collapseActiveRoute = getActiveRoute(routes[i].views);
        if (collapseActiveRoute !== activeRoute) {
          return collapseActiveRoute;
        }
      } else {
        if (
          window.location.href.indexOf(routes[i].layout + routes[i].path) !== -1
        ) {
          return routes[i].name;
        }
      }
    }
    return activeRoute;
  };
  const getRoutes = routes => {
    return routes.map((prop, key) => {
      if (prop.collapse) {
        return getRoutes(prop.views);
      }
      if (prop.layout === "/admin") {
        return (
          <Route
            path={prop.layout + prop.path}
            component={prop.component}
            key={key}
          />
        );
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    });
  };
  const sidebarMinimize = () => {
    setMiniActive(!miniActive);
  };
  const resizeFunction = () => {
    if (window.innerWidth >= 960) {
      setMobileOpen(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.wrapper}>
      <Sidebar
        routes={routes}
        logoText={"My App"}
        logo={logo}
        image={image}
        handleDrawerToggle={handleDrawerToggle}
        open={mobileOpen}
        color={color}
        bgColor={bgColor}
        miniActive={miniActive}
        {...rest}
      />
      <div className={mainPanelClasses} ref={mainPanel}>
        <AdminNavbar
          sidebarMinimize={sidebarMinimize.bind(this)}
          miniActive={miniActive}
          brandText={getActiveRoute(routes)}
          handleDrawerToggle={handleDrawerToggle}
          {...rest}
        />
        {/* On the /maps/full-screen-maps route we want the map to be on full screen - this is not possible if the content and conatiner classes are present because they have some paddings which would make the map smaller */}
        {getRoute() ? (
          <div className={classes.content}>
            <div className={classes.container}>
              <Switch>
                {getRoutes(routes)}
                <Redirect from="/admin" to="/admin/dashboard" />
              </Switch>
            </div>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div className={classes.map}>
            <Switch>
              {getRoutes(routes)}
              <Redirect from="/admin" to="/admin/dashboard" />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        )}
        {getRoute() ? <Footer fluid /> : null}
        <FixedPlugin
          handleImageClick={handleImageClick}
          handleColorClick={handleColorClick}
          handleBgColorClick={handleBgColorClick}
          color={color}
          bgColor={bgColor}
          bgImage={image}
          handleFixedClick={handleFixedClick}
          fixedClasses={fixedClasses}
          sidebarMinimize={sidebarMinimize.bind(this)}
          miniActive={miniActive}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

My routes.js file (wanting to translate the "name" item)

```
const dashRoutes = [
  {
    path: "/dashboard",
    name: "Dashboard", <--- need to translate this t("Dashboard") and subsequent name attributes below
    rtlName: "لوحة القيادة",
    icon: DashboardIcon,
    component: Dashboard,
    layout: "/admin"
  },
  {
    collapse: true,
    name: "Pages",
    rtlName: "صفحات",
    icon: Image,
    state: "pageCollapse",
    views: [
      {
        path: "/pricing-page",
        name: "Pricing Page",
        rtlName: "عالتسعير",
        mini: "PP",
        rtlMini: "ع",
        component: PricingPage,
        layout: "/auth"
      },
      {
        path: "/rtl-support-page",
        name: "RTL Support",
        rtlName: "صودعم رتل",
        mini: "RS",
        rtlMini: "صو",
        component: RTLSupport,
        layout: "/rtl"
      },
      {
        path: "/timeline-page",
        name: "Timeline Page",
        rtlName: "تيالجدول الزمني",
        mini: "T",
        rtlMini: "تي",
        component: TimelinePage,
        layout: "/admin"
      },
      {
        path: "/login-page",
        name: "Login Page",
        rtlName: "هعذاتسجيل الدخول",
        mini: "L",
        rtlMini: "هعذا",
        component: LoginPage,
        layout: "/auth"
      },
      {
        path: "/register-page",
        name: "Register Page",
        rtlName: "تسجيل",
        mini: "R",
        rtlMini: "صع",
        component: RegisterPage,
        layout: "/auth"
      },
      {
        path: "/lock-screen-page",
        name: "Lock Screen Page",
        rtlName: "اقفل الشاشة",
        mini: "LS",
        rtlMini: "هذاع",
        component: LockScreenPage,
        layout: "/auth"
      },
      {
        path: "/user-page",
        name: "User Profile",
        rtlName: "ملف تعريفي للمستخدم",
        mini: "UP",
        rtlMini: "شع",
        component: UserProfile,
        layout: "/admin"
      },
      {
        path: "/error-page",
        name: "Error Page",
        rtlName: "صفحة الخطأ",
        mini: "E",
        rtlMini: "البريد",
        component: ErrorPage,
        layout: "/auth"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    collapse: true,
    name: "Components",
    rtlName: "المكونات",
    icon: Apps,
    state: "componentsCollapse",
    views: [
      {
        collapse: true,
        name: "Multi Level Collapse",
        rtlName: "انهيار متعدد المستويات",
        mini: "MC",
        rtlMini: "ر",
        state: "multiCollapse",
        views: [
          {
            path: "/buttons",
            name: "Buttons",
            rtlName: "وصفت",
            mini: "B",
            rtlMini: "ب",
            component: Buttons,
            layout: "/admin"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: "/buttons",
        name: "Buttons",
        rtlName: "وصفت",
        mini: "B",
        rtlMini: "ب",
        component: Buttons,
        layout: "/admin"
      },
      {
        path: "/grid-system",
        name: "Grid System",
        rtlName: "نظام الشبكة",
        mini: "GS",
        rtlMini: "زو",
        component: GridSystem,
        layout: "/admin"
      },
      {
        path: "/panels",
        name: "Panels",
        rtlName: "لوحات",
        mini: "P",
        rtlMini: "ع",
        component: Panels,
        layout: "/admin"
      },
      {
        path: "/sweet-alert",
        name: "Sweet Alert",
        rtlName: "الحلو تنبيه",
        mini: "SA",
        rtlMini: "ومن",
        component: SweetAlert,
        layout: "/admin"
      },
      {
        path: "/notifications",
        name: "Notifications",
        rtlName: "إخطارات",
        mini: "N",
        rtlMini: "ن",
        component: Notifications,
        layout: "/admin"
      },
      {
        path: "/icons",
        name: "Icons",
        rtlName: "الرموز",
        mini: "I",
        rtlMini: "و",
        component: Icons,
        layout: "/admin"
      },
      {
        path: "/typography",
        name: "Typography",
        rtlName: "طباعة",
        mini: "T",
        rtlMini: "ر",
        component: Typography,
        layout: "/admin"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    collapse: true,
    name: "Forms",
    rtlName: "إستمارات",
    icon: "content_paste",
    state: "formsCollapse",
    views: [
      {
        path: "/regular-forms",
        name: "Regular Forms",
        rtlName: "أشكال عادية",
        mini: "RF",
        rtlMini: "صو",
        component: RegularForms,
        layout: "/admin"
      },
      {
        path: "/extended-forms",
        name: "Extended Forms",
        rtlName: "نماذج موسعة",
        mini: "EF",
        rtlMini: "هوو",
        component: ExtendedForms,
        layout: "/admin"
      },
      {
        path: "/validation-forms",
        name: "Validation Forms",
        rtlName: "نماذج التحقق من الصحة",
        mini: "VF",
        rtlMini: "تو",
        component: ValidationForms,
        layout: "/admin"
      },
      {
        path: "/wizard",
        name: "Wizard",
        rtlName: "ساحر",
        mini: "W",
        rtlMini: "ث",
        component: Wizard,
        layout: "/admin"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    collapse: true,
    name: "Tables",
    rtlName: "الجداول",
    icon: GridOn,
    state: "tablesCollapse",
    views: [
      {
        path: "/regular-tables",
        name: "Regular Tables",
        rtlName: "طاولات عادية",
        mini: "RT",
        rtlMini: "صر",
        component: RegularTables,
        layout: "/admin"
      },
      {
        path: "/extended-tables",
        name: "Extended Tables",
        rtlName: "جداول ممتدة",
        mini: "ET",
        rtlMini: "هور",
        component: ExtendedTables,
        layout: "/admin"
      },
      {
        path: "/react-tables",
        name: "React Tables",
        rtlName: "رد فعل الطاولة",
        mini: "RT",
        rtlMini: "در",
        component: ReactTables,
        layout: "/admin"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    collapse: true,
    name: "Maps",
    rtlName: "خرائط",
    icon: Place,
    state: "mapsCollapse",
    views: [
      {
        path: "/google-maps",
        name: "Google Maps",
        rtlName: "خرائط جوجل",
        mini: "GM",
        rtlMini: "زم",
        component: GoogleMaps,
        layout: "/admin"
      },
      {
        path: "/full-screen-maps",
        name: "Full Screen Map",
        rtlName: "خريطة كاملة الشاشة",
        mini: "FSM",
        rtlMini: "ووم",
        component: FullScreenMap,
        layout: "/admin"
      },
      {
        path: "/vector-maps",
        name: "Vector Map",
        rtlName: "خريطة المتجه",
        mini: "VM",
        rtlMini: "تم",
        component: VectorMap,
        layout: "/admin"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: "/widgets",
    name: "Widgets",
    rtlName: "الحاجيات",
    icon: WidgetsIcon,
    component: Widgets,
    layout: "/admin"
  },
  {
    path: "/charts",
    name: "Charts",
    rtlName: "الرسوم البيانية",
    icon: Timeline,
    component: Charts,
    layout: "/admin"
  },
  {
    path: "/calendar",
    name: "Calendar",
    rtlName: "التقويم",
    icon: DateRange,
    component: Calendar,
    layout: "/admin"
  }
];
export default dashRoutes;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this.

```
import { withTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import i18n from "../../../../i18n"  // import here your i18n file

const dashRoutes = [
  {
    path: "/dashboard",
    name: i18n("Dashboard"), <--- need to translate this t("Dashboard") and subsequent name attributes below
    rtlName: "لوحة القيادة",
    icon: DashboardIcon,
    component: Dashboard,
    layout: "/admin"
  },
  {
    collapse: true,
    name: i18n("Page"),
    rtlName: "صفحات",
    icon: Image,
    state: "pageCollapse",

 ......

export default withTranslation()(dashRoutes);
```

or you can use `useTranslation`

```
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
const {t} = useTranslation();

const dashRoutes = [
  {
    path: "/dashboard",
    name: t("Dashboard"), <--- need to translate this t("Dashboard") and subsequent name attributes below
    rtlName: "لوحة القيادة",
    icon: DashboardIcon,
    component: Dashboard,
    layout: "/admin"
  },
...
```

i hope it can help you to translate your array name .

Comment: Thanks for that but that's what I've been trying to do. 
Your option 1 gives:
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function


Your option 2 gives:
Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Comment: can you show me your error snapshot? @StevenDavisworth