# How to use react-i18next with createBrowserRourter in React Router v6.22.2?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom, react-i18next

I'm wondering if anybody has used the react-i18next library with the latest React Router v6 and the `createBrowserRouter()`.

I'm experiencing the following warning in my web application:
[image: i18next warning]

In React Router `v6` the suggested router is `createBrowserRouter()` which needs to know all the routes ahead of time. My file structure has the routes in the `index.ts` of each page's directory and in that `index.ts` file I'm defining some meta data about the page.

The meta data is a `const` and includes the name of the page which is wrapped in `i18n.t()` which is causing warnings about using the function before the library has been initialized. I'm wondering if there are any best practices that should be followed in scenarios like this.

I'm hoping somebody has done this before or can maybe point me in the right direction?

The pseudo file structure/code looks like similar to this (I didn't define all the objects properly):

**main.tsx**

```
import routes from 'routes.ts'

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  ...router config and routes
])

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'!).render(
  <RouteProvider router=router/>
))
```

**routes.ts**

```
import routes1 from '.page1'
import routes2 from '.page2'

const routes = [
  routes1,
  routes2,
  ...
]

export default routes;
```

**page1/index.ts**

```
const metaData = {
  title: i18n.t('Page Title')
  ...
}

const routes = [
  {route with meta Data}
  ...
]

export default routes;
```

1. I've considered changing the `const metadata = [...]` to a function like `getPageData(i18n)`.
2. I've considered changing the routes so each page has a `getRoutes()` function that is executed after i18n has been initialized. And then I would call `getAllRoute()` in the `main.ts` where `createBrowserRouter()` is defined.

Edit: Here is a CodeSandbox [minimal reproducible example](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/i18next-react-router-3cgx5t?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A10%2C13&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltop2l9f0006356itkrvq1i2%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltop2l9f0002356i1702ntn1%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltop2l9f0003356i34myqyjx%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltop2l9f0005356in747ufrk%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522cltop2l9f0002356i1702ntn1%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltop2l9f0002356i1702ntn1%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltopu8470002356ihhrw2pha%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A10%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A13%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A10%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A13%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FApp.tsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cltopu8470002356ihhrw2pha%2522%257D%252C%2522cltop2l9f0005356in747ufrk%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltop2l9f0004356ijc5g1d4j%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltop2l9f0005356in747ufrk%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cltop2l9f0004356ijc5g1d4j%2522%257D%252C%2522cltop2l9f0003356i34myqyjx%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltop2l9f0003356i34myqyjx%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D) as requested. If you inspect developer tools you will see the issue warning from above.

Edit: [I think I found a solution](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/i18next-react-router-forked-lfqm6q?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.tsx%3A15%2C45-16%2C12&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltoqb1qt0006356i82l75sxj%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltoqb1qt0002356i0xbn1w42%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltoqb1qt0003356itg826egn%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltoqb1qt0005356i3y2ngoc3%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B52.02310477613656%252C47.97689522386344%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522cltoqb1qt0002356i0xbn1w42%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltoqb1qt0001356iqr4uujpo%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Findex.tsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A15%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A45%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A16%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A12%257D%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltoqb1qt0002356i0xbn1w42%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cltoqb1qt0001356iqr4uujpo%2522%257D%252C%2522cltoqb1qt0005356i3y2ngoc3%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltoqb1qt0004356ipuhft98k%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltoqb1qt0005356i3y2ngoc3%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cltoqb1qt0004356ipuhft98k%2522%257D%252C%2522cltoqb1qt0003356itg826egn%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltoqb1qt0003356itg826egn%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

Edit: Here's an example route that's more descriptive

```
const routes: RouteObject[] = [{
  path: "/example",
  handle: {
    // I'm not sure how to use the translate function properly below
    text: t("Example Page"),
    crumb: (data: object) => ({ ...data, text: t("Example Page") }),
  },
  element: <ExamplePage />,
  ...
}]

export default routes;
```

**TLDR:** I have strings in the `handle` key of my `RouteObjects[]` that need to use the react-i18next translate function but I'm not sure the correct way to wait for the react-i18n to finish initializing before using it.

Comment: Where is your i18n code/logic? Please [edit] to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with?

Comment: @DrewReese when I get a chance I can provide the minimal reproducible example you requested.

Comment: None of my solutions have worked 100% so far but I found this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60444971/how-to-implement-react-i18next-in-a-routes-js-file

Comment: That doesn't seem too far off from the code you have in your post. Can you [edit] to add a [mcve] of the code you are using? In the meantime I'll take a peek at your sandboxes that I just noticed you had added a few hours ago. And sorry, can you clarify what the issue or problem is with your code? Where are you initializing the i18n code, or expecting it to be initialized?

Comment: I have followed the `react-i18next` documentation and am initializing the `i18n` object in my `i18n.ts` file that is imported in the `main.tsx` file of my app. I'm essentially loading the i18n as soon as possible.

Comment: Why do you need localization coupled to the router itself? I'm still not understanding what you are trying to accomplish here. I was going to suggest that if you need the i18n code before creating the router to simply import that code higher in the ReactTree so that it is instantiated/initialized earlier, but it looks like you did that in your second sandbox.

Comment: @DrewReese in my main page layout I have a nav menu and page crumbs that I generate using the data returned from the route handle. To get that data I use the `useMatches` hook and ome of the data in that handle needs to be translated based on the users language.

Comment: I see. Why not just pass the string key in the route handle, and use the translate function in the UI like normal? Is there any reason to pass the translations through the router code? Or is *this* the specific piece you need help with?

Comment: @DrewReese I suppose I could do that. However I'm also using react-18next-parser to find all of my english messages in my code and generate the json files for the other languages. Is this considered bad practice? I know the parser also detects comments so I could edit all my code so right above the actual page name there is a comment like `// t("Example Page")` but that seems like a code smell to me.